# Почему декоратор сохраняет состояние?

Tags: python, декоратор

**Почему с каждым новым вызовом a_plus_b состояние buffer не обнуляется?**

Реализуйте декоратор result_accumulator, который модернизирует функцию с неопределенным количеством позиционных параметров следующим образом:

1. Добавляет именованный параметр method со значением по умолчанию accumulate;
2. При вызове функции с параметром method равным accumulate, результат сохраняется в очередь (для каждой функции в собственную), а функция ничего не возвращает;
3. При вызове функции с параметром method равным drop, возвращается все накопленные результаты, а очередь сбрасывается.

```py
def result_accumulator(func):
    buffer = []

    def decorator(*args, method='accumulate'):
        nonlocal buffer
        buffer.append(func(*args))
        if method == 'drop':
            answer = buffer
            buffer = []
            return answer

    return decorator

@result_accumulator
def a_plus_b(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Comment: Потому что создается "замыкание" - объект с локальными переменными, связанный с функцией decorator на момент ее создания (в момент вызова декоратора result_accumulator)